# my internal hard disk is not mounting used to mount before.. suddenly stopped

Tags: 14.04

Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sda3: Command-line `mount "/mnt/5CE0040FE003EDD8"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the error message tells it all: at some point, your filesystem was not cleanly unmounted. This has been flagged, and the system will now not mount it until it has been checked. To do this, you need to :

- In a terminal, become superuser

  ```
  sudo bash
  ```
- If the filesystem is mounted, unmount it

  ```
  umount /dev/sda3
  ```
- Check the (now unmounted) filesystem

  ```
  ntfsfix /dev/sda3
  ```
- You can now remount it as indicated in /etc/fstab:

  ```
  mount /dev/sda3
  ```

HTH.

Comment: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Remount failed: Operation not permitted
'